# pyodbc - SQL Server does not exist or access denied problem

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I have a problem connecting to one of my mssql servers using pyodbc.

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ZZZ\instance;PORT=1433;DATABASE=ZZZ;UID=ZZZ;PWD=ZZZ')
```

I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
```

I can connect to the server with Excel with a test file I created (test.dqy).

```
XLODBC
1
Driver={SQL Server};server=ZZZ;uid=ZZZ;pwd=ZZZ;
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Comment: Microsoft's ODBC Drivers for SQL Server do not support a `PORT=` connection-string argument. If you want to specify the port you need to append it to the `SERVER=` argument with a comma, e.g., `SERVER=ZZZ,51433`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to connect to an instance of an SQL server I forgot to use an additional slash to escape the slash for the instance.

Now it's working without any problems.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a raw string: `r'...;SERVER=servername\instancename;...'`